# math error python - trying to do simple trigonometry

Tags: python, math

I'm doing some maths and have to do a table of values with sin of x.

I figured that this would be quicker in Python and nice to learn two things at once... But I'm currently getting a maths error.

Here's the code :

```
import math

ang = math.asin(30)

print ang
```

And here's the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tri/Desktop/maths.py", line 3, in <module>
    ang = math.asin(30)
ValueError: math domain error
>>>
```

I've looked at some other posts but can't really follow them through.

Comment: Range of sinus is from -1 to 1

Comment: And in radians it's −π/2 ≤ y ≤ π/2

Comment: yes... sorry I thought that it would work like sin(30) does on my calculator.

Comment: You're using `asin` not `sin` (other than the degrees/radians problem)

Comment: @Trengot thanks - I changed the code to `sin` instead of `asin`, yet the answer returned is 0.85 where as my calculator returns 0.71 (to 2 decimal places) Is there any reason for this difference? `ang = math.sin(45)` is the code, thank you

Comment: @user3130747 As others have mentioned, your calculator uses degrees, python's `math` expects radians. Use `math.radians(x)` to convert, i.e. `math.sin(math.radians(180))` is the equivalent to sin(180) in the calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arcsine function is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) outside [-1, 1]. In other words, 30 is outside the function's [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function). This is precisely what the exception is telling you.

If you are looking for the sine function, it is called [`math.sin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sin) and expects its argument to be in radians. To convert from degrees to radians, use [`math.radians()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.radians).

Comment: Thanks... I didn't realize that it worked that way, because I had been doing them on my calculator by entering sin(30) and getting the answer (0.5) , I thought that the python function might work the same way.

Comment: @user3130747: You are confusing sine and arcsine. They are inverses of each other.

Comment: thanks @NPE, I changed it to use the `sin` instead of `asin`, it doesn't return an error, but it doesn't return the right (or what I would expect) answer either.... `ang = math.sin(45)` returns 0.85, where as `sin(45)` on my calculator returns `0.71`, I don't understand where the difference is coming from... cheers

Comment: @user3130747: Please take the time to read my (very short) answer. The mystery is explained in the second paragraph.

Comment: indeed, thanks NPE, forest for the trees there. Radians are new so maybe I just (unintentionally) ignored that word.... thanks all the same!

Answer (score 4):

Python's  [math.asin(x)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.asin) returns the arc sine of x, but `x` is measured in radians.  You're trying it with degrees.

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions), we can see that the argument should be between -1 and 1.

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) explains the conversion between radians and degrees.

Comment: cheers, I thought that It was like when I use my calculator and enter sin(30), that's what I thought the function did.... What is it that I want to do then (to achieve the same result as I get from my calculator) thanks

Comment: Read the third link I put in my answer.  It explains the conversion between degrees and radians.  You'll have to know this eventually anyway.